# Search for `count' distinct odd numbers that are smaller than `bound' and add up to `sum'

Tags: c, recursion

I am working on a problem that finds 'count' odd numbers below the int value 'bound' and adds up to an int value sum.  It is suggested that I use recursion to solve.

I have completed the recursion and have made it solve 7 / 8 cases in mimir.  There is one case that is showing a fail but I cannot figure out what is wrong even when stepping through with gdb.
Problem case:
Input: 10 54 108

EDIT:
So it turns out that my code is correct and is finding the correct answer for this case ( AKA - No solution exists ) but my problem is that I only have 3 sec of run time to find this solution and currently my code takes longer than that.

Not looking for a straight answer necessarily, more of a point in the right direction.  Trying to learn from this :)

https://ibb.co/4138WBw

```
int odd_sum(int count, int bound, int sum)
{
    if (bound % 2 == 0)
        return odd_sum(count, bound -1, sum);
    else if ( sum == 0 && count == 0 && bound >= -1)
        return 1;
    else if ( sum - bound < 0)
        return odd_sum(count, bound - 2, sum);
    else if (count == 0 && sum != 0)
        return 0;
    else if (bound < 1 && sum != 0)
        return 0;
    else
    {
        int value = (odd_sum(count - 1, bound - 2, sum - bound));

        if ( value )
        {
            return printf("%d ", bound);
        }
        else
            return (odd_sum(count - 1, bound - 2, sum - bound));
    }

/* Do not change the main() function */
int main(void)
{
    int value;
    int c, b, s;

    printf("Please enter 3 positive integers: count, bound, and sum:\n");
    if (scanf("%d%d%d", &c, &b, &s) != 3) {
        printf("Please enter 3 integers.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (c <= 0 || b <= 0 || s <= 0) {
        printf("Integers must be positive.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    value = odd_sum(c, b, s);
    if (value)
        printf("\n");
    else
        printf("There are no solutions.\n");
    return 0;
}


The final result needs to look like this for the two cases, ( pass or fail )

$./odd_sum
Please enter 3 positive integers: count, bound, and sum:
10 20 100
1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19

$./odd_sum
Please enter 3 positive integers: count, bound, and sum:
10 18 100
There are no solutions.

$./odd_sum
Please enter 3 positive integers: count, bound, and sum:
12 30 200
5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 23 25 27 29

Thank you guys in advance
```

Comment: Pretty sure that I am just missing a specific case at the moment.  If im correct its a case that if bound > -1 and count > 0 but sum != 0 then skip a value and continue forward.  I am just unsure of how to go about writing it

Comment: `bound > -1 && count > 0 && sum != 0` is always true for every step but the last in your recursion.  It is not the case you're looking for.

Comment: The problem is that when considering whether to include the current `bound` as one of the selected numbers, you do not take into account how many more numbers you need to accommodate in the sum.  As a result, if `bound` is larger than it needs to be then you select numbers that are too large, and run out of `sum` before you run out of `count`.

Comment: One last hint: the sum of the first *n* positive odd numbers is *n* squared.

Comment: odd numbers used should == count,
they must print out from least to greatest number and equal the sum of 108,
odd numbers do not need to be consecutive

Comment: image link to the excersize specifications edited into post

Comment: If the `odd` numbers _do not need to be consecutive_ then your program does not employ any intelligence to calculate the summation of non consecutive odd number to check whether it is equal to `sum` or not. You need to revisit the logic of your program. Also, all the input validation's should be done just after user input.

Comment: Im not allowed to change main in this assignment.  And yes I know that my program does not employ any intelligence, new to programming and the c language and stumped after 3 days of working on this assignment and another one.  Heard you guys are good at helping with code and stearing in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to return the correct result for input, (10, 54, 108): `1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 27`

```
int odd_sum(int count, int bound, int sum){
  if (count == 0 && sum == 0)
    return 1;
  if (count == 0 || bound <= 0)
    return 0;
  if (bound % 2 == 0)
    return odd_sum(count, bound - 1, sum);
  if (odd_sum(count - 1, bound - 2, sum - bound))
    return printf("%d ", bound);
  else
    return odd_sum(count, bound - 2, sum);
  return 0;
}
```